# Building Library with OpenCV for android fails on "not building target XXX because there was no build command for it"

Tags: android, c++, opencv, gradle, android-ndk

I have a working c++ library that was compiled on mac using cmake and already running. I am now trying to compile it for Android using Android studio and gradle.
When I try to compile it using Android studio I am getting a cryptic linker error so I tried to compile it in command line using a gradle wrapper and then I got the following errors:

```
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_calib3d because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_core because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_features2d because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_flann because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_highgui because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_imgcodecs because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_imgproc because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_ml because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_objdetect because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_photo because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_shape because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_stitching because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_superres because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_video because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_videoio because there was no build command for it
externalNativeBuildRelease: not building target opencv_videostab because there was no build command for it 
...
```

I couldn't find an explanation for this issue.
My CMakelists.txt include the lines:

```
set (OpenCV_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-876c2c0_4/share/OpenCV)
set (CMAKE_MODULE_PATH /usr/local/Cellar/opencv3/HEAD-876c2c0_4/share/OpenCV)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
```

and it seems to find it but cannot build it. If anyone has any idea how to solve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I was using opencv binaries compiled for macos
I downloaded the android sdk from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/

and it seems to work